# Geocoding large dataset for use in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, geolocation, mapkit, geocoding, core-location

Problem:   I have a large sqlite database of roughly 500000 US addresses that I include in my iPhone application.  I want to show the closest 10 to a given location as MKAnnotations on a MKMapView.

Option 1: Search database by zipcode to get a smaller number of addresses.   Just choose the first 10 and geocode them online, display on map.

Option 2: Pre-geocode entire database offline, storing lat,lon in the sqlite db.  Search by zipcode.  Use CLLocation's to find the closest 10 in the data returned.

Is there any other option I haven't thought of?   I am currently looking into option 2.  I downloaded the Planet.OSM database from OpenStreetMaps. But I got a little lost on what to do next.  I probably need to setup a local instance of Nominatim?   Not really sure.